# Webpack app in docker needs environment variables before it can be built

Tags: docker, webpack, environment-variables

New to docker so maybe I'm missing something obvious...

I have an app split into a web client and a back end server. The back end is pretty easy to create an image for via a Dockerfile:

1. `COPY` source
2. `RUN` `npm install`, `npm run build`
3. `CMD` `npm run start`

The already-built back end app will then access the environment variables at runtime.

With the web client it's not as simple because webpack needs to have the environment variables *before* the application is built. This leaves me as far as I'm aware only two options:

1. Require the user to build their own image from the application source
2. Build the web client on `container run` by running `npm run build` in `CMD`

Currently I'm doing **#2** but both options seem wrong to me. What's the best solution?

```
FROM node:latest
COPY ./server /app/server
COPY ./web /app/web
WORKDIR /app/web
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm install && npm run build && cd ../server && npm install && npm run build && npm run start"]
```

Comment: You could instruct them to use `FROM` and `ENV` in a new Dockerfile and `ONBUILD` in your original container to do the building.

Comment: Can you post the Dockerfile you have so far for the web client, so we can see where the variables will need to be used?

Comment: Another option is to pass a file in a volume and write an entrypoint script that parses that file, sets variables and potentially uses a pre-existing build. If the container restarts, this will reduce the response time. Also, is it possible to do most of the building on build and reduce the part requiring environment variables into a smaller operation? Like replace a config.js containing defaults with values from the env.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it would be a good idea for both the backend server and web client to each have their own Dockerfile/image. Then it would be easy to run them together using something like `docker-compose`.

The way you are going to want to provide environment variables to the web Dockerfile is by using build arguments. Docker build arguments are available when building the Docker image. You use these by specifying the `ARG` key in the Dockerfile, or by passing the `--build-arg` flag to `docker build`.

Here is an example `Dockerfile` for your web client based on what you provided:

```
FROM node:latest

ARG NODE_ENV=dev

COPY ./web /app/web
WORKDIR /app/web

RUN npm install \
    && npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

The following `Dockerfile` uses the `ARG` directive to create a variable with a default value of `dev`.

The value of `NODE_ENV` can then be overridden when running `docker build`.

Like so:

```
docker build -t <myimage> --build-arg NODE_ENV=production .
```

Whether you override it or not `NODE_ENV` will be available to webpack before it is built. This allows you to build a single image, and distribute it to many people without them having to build the web client.

Hopefully this helps you out.